# Best fitting line for a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to find the best fitting line for a scatter plot if I don't know the relationship between 2 axes(else I could have used scipy.optimize).My scatter plot looks something like this

[image: scatterplot]

I would like to have a line like this
[image: expected_result]
and i need to get the points of the best fitting line for my further calculation

```
for j in lat :
l=94*j
i=l-92
for lines in itertools.islice(input_file, i, l):
    lines=lines.split()
    p.append(float(Decimal(lines[0])))
    vmr.append(float(Decimal(lines[3])))
    plt.scatter(vmr, p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LOWESS (Locally Weighted Scatterplot Smoothing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression), a non-parametric regression method.

`Statsmodels` has an implementation [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html) that you can use to fit your own smoother.

See this [StackOverflow question on visualizing nonlinear relationships in scatter plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784399/how-to-visualize-a-nonlinear-relationship-in-a-scatter-plot) for an example using the `Statsmodels` implementation.

You could also use the implementation in the `Seaborn` visuzalization library's `regplot()` function with the keyword argument `lowess=True`. See the [Seaborn documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html#seaborn.regplot) for details.

The following code is an example using `Seaborn` and the data from the StackOverflow question above:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("white")

x = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
ytrue = np.exp(-x/5.0) + 2*np.sin(x/3.0)

# add random errors with a normal distribution                      
y = ytrue + np.random.normal(size=len(x))

sns.regplot(x, y, lowess=True, color="black", 
            line_kws={"color":"magenta", "linewidth":5})
```

[image: resulting figure]

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't a matplotlib question, but I think you can do this kind of thing with pandas, using a rolling median.

```
smoothedData = dataSeries.rolling(10, center = True).median()
```

Actually you can do a rolling median with anything, but pandas has a built in function. Numpy may too.