# How to compute and plot a LOWESS curve in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics, statsmodels

How can I find and plot a LOWESS curve that looks like the following using Python?

[image: loess curve example]

I'm aware of the LOWESS implementation [in statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html), but it doesn't seem to be able to give me 95% confidence interval lines that I can shade between.  Seaborn [has a method](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) that calls the statsmodels implementation, but it can't plot the confidence intervals.

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536191/how-to-filter-smooth-with-scipy-numpy) StackOverflow [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784399/how-to-visualize-a-nonlinear-relationship-in-a-scatter-plot) give code to draw a LOESS/LOWESS line, but none with a confidence interval. Can anyone assist with this? Is anyone aware of an existing implementation that would enable me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59747610/5855131

Comment: @ted930511 Thanks, but no; it looks like the previous comments were archived, but this question is about computing the appropriate confidence interval for a LOWESS curve.  For searchers, the current answer is "use R if you want to compute LOWESS confidence intervals" or "implement them yourself from the original paper" if you must use Python.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to implement by yourself. Pls check this [link](https://james-brennan.github.io/posts/lowess_conf/)

Comment: Yup, looks like that blog post provides a usable implementation.  I wish it had existed 3 years ago! If you leave an answer with that link and a short note on the contents of the blog, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a link [here](https://james-brennan.github.io/posts/lowess_conf/) is useful, and I put code below:

```
def lowess(x, y, f=1./3.):
    """
    Basic LOWESS smoother with uncertainty. 
    Note:
        - Not robust (so no iteration) and
             only normally distributed errors. 
        - No higher order polynomials d=1 
            so linear smoother.
    """
    # get some paras
    xwidth = f*(x.max()-x.min()) # effective width after reduction factor
    N = len(x) # number of obs
    # Don't assume the data is sorted
    order = np.argsort(x)
    # storage
    y_sm = np.zeros_like(y)
    y_stderr = np.zeros_like(y)
    # define the weigthing function -- clipping too!
    tricube = lambda d : np.clip((1- np.abs(d)**3)**3, 0, 1)
    # run the regression for each observation i
    for i in range(N):
        dist = np.abs((x[order][i]-x[order]))/xwidth
        w = tricube(dist)
        # form linear system with the weights
        A = np.stack([w, x[order]*w]).T
        b = w * y[order]
        ATA = A.T.dot(A)
        ATb = A.T.dot(b)
        # solve the syste
        sol = np.linalg.solve(ATA, ATb)
        # predict for the observation only
        yest = A[i].dot(sol)# equiv of A.dot(yest) just for k
        place = order[i]
        y_sm[place]=yest 
        sigma2 = (np.sum((A.dot(sol) -y [order])**2)/N )
        # Calculate the standard error
        y_stderr[place] = np.sqrt(sigma2 * 
                                A[i].dot(np.linalg.inv(ATA)
                                                    ).dot(A[i]))
    return y_sm, y_stderr


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# make some data
x = 5*np.random.random(100)
y = np.sin(x) * 3*np.exp(-x) + np.random.normal(0, 0.2, 100)
order = np.argsort(x)

#run it
y_sm, y_std = lowess(x, y, f=1./5.)
# plot it
plt.plot(x[order], y_sm[order], color='tomato', label='LOWESS')
plt.fill_between(x[order], y_sm[order] - 1.96*y_std[order],
                 y_sm[order] + 1.96*y_std[order], alpha=0.3, label='LOWESS uncertainty')
plt.plot(x, y, 'k.', label='Observations')
plt.legend(loc='best')
#run it
y_sm, y_std = lowess(x, y, f=1./5.)
# plot it
plt.plot(x[order], y_sm[order], color='tomato', label='LOWESS')
plt.fill_between(x[order], y_sm[order] - y_std[order],
                 y_sm[order] + y_std[order], alpha=0.3, label='LOWESS uncertainty')
plt.plot(x, y, 'k.', label='Observations')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]