# How can I plot a confidence interval in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, confidence-interval

I recently started to use Python, and I can't understand how to plot a confidence interval for a given datum (or set of data).

I already have a function that computes, given a set of measurements, a higher and lower bound depending on the confidence level that I pass to it, but how can I use those two values to plot a confidence interval?

Comment: A good article about the topic of Confidence intervals in general, with some Python code: https://towardsdatascience.com/illustration-with-python-confidence-interval-ee4736cc3dc2

Answer (score 86):

There are several ways to accomplish what you asking for:

**Using only `matplotlib`**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#some example data
x = np.linspace(0.1, 9.9, 20)
y = 3.0 * x
#some confidence interval
ci = 1.96 * np.std(y)/np.sqrt(len(x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.fill_between(x, (y-ci), (y+ci), color='b', alpha=.1)
```

`fill_between` does what you are looking for. For more information on how to use this function, see: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html

**Output**

[image]

Alternatively, go for `seaborn`, which supports this using `lineplot` or `regplot`,
see: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

Comment: Why do you divide by the mean? In `ci = 1.96 * np.std(y)/np.mean(y)`. Shouldn't it by the square root of the sample size? According to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps

Comment: @CGFoX This is only a toy example. I agree, you would use the standard error. For illustration I used the mean which is not correct. The confidence interval for a linear regression is indeed even more intricate to calculate using the fitted parameters and a t-distribution for unknown SDs, which here is assumed to be normal hence 1.96 for 95 % confidence.

Comment: Excellent solution! How can we add a label for the confidence interval to show in the legend?

Comment: @maximus You can supply a label string for the legend using `label` as argument when calling `ax.fill_between` .

Answer (score 18):

Let's assume that we have three categories and lower and upper bounds of confidence intervals of a certain estimator across these three categories:

```
data_dict = {}
data_dict['category'] = ['category 1','category 2','category 3']
data_dict['lower'] = [0.1,0.2,0.15]
data_dict['upper'] = [0.22,0.3,0.21]
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

You can plot the confidence interval for each of these categories using the following code:

```
for lower,upper,y in zip(dataset['lower'],dataset['upper'],range(len(dataset))):
    plt.plot((lower,upper),(y,y),'ro-',color='orange')
plt.yticks(range(len(dataset)),list(dataset['category']))
```

Resulting with the following graph:

[image: Confidence intervals of an estimator across some three categories]

Answer (score 11):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics
from math import sqrt


def plot_confidence_interval(x, values, z=1.96, color='#2187bb', horizontal_line_width=0.25):
    mean = statistics.mean(values)
    stdev = statistics.stdev(values)
    confidence_interval = z * stdev / sqrt(len(values))

    left = x - horizontal_line_width / 2
    top = mean - confidence_interval
    right = x + horizontal_line_width / 2
    bottom = mean + confidence_interval
    plt.plot([x, x], [top, bottom], color=color)
    plt.plot([left, right], [top, top], color=color)
    plt.plot([left, right], [bottom, bottom], color=color)
    plt.plot(x, mean, 'o', color='#f44336')

    return mean, confidence_interval


plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4], ['FF', 'BF', 'FFD', 'BFD'])
plt.title('Confidence Interval')
plot_confidence_interval(1, [10, 11, 42, 45, 44])
plot_confidence_interval(2, [10, 21, 42, 45, 44])
plot_confidence_interval(3, [20, 2, 4, 45, 44])
plot_confidence_interval(4, [30, 31, 42, 45, 44])
plt.show()
```

- `x`: The x value of the input.
- `values`: An array containing the repeated values (usually measured values) of y corresponding to the value of x.
- `z`: The critical value of the z-distribution. Using `1.96` corresponds to the critical value of `95%`.

Result:

[image: code output]

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70949996/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Very good! You can also use hlines and vlines instead of plot

Answer (score 2):

For a confidence interval across categories, building on what [omer sagi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747313/how-can-i-plot-a-confidence-interval-in-python/63262037#63262037), let's say if we have a Pandas data frame with a column that contains categories (like `category 1`, `category 2`, and `category 3`) and another that has continuous data (like some kind of `rating`), here's a function using `pd.groupby()` and `scipy.stats` to plot difference in means across groups with confidence intervals:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

def plot_diff_in_means(data: pd.DataFrame, col1: str, col2: str):
    """
    Given data, plots difference in means with confidence intervals across groups
    col1: categorical data with groups
    col2: continuous data for the means
    """
    n = data.groupby(col1)[col2].count()
    # n contains a pd.Series with sample size for each category

    cat = list(data.groupby(col1, as_index=False)[col2].count()[col1])
    # 'cat' has the names of the categories, like 'category 1', 'category 2'

    mean = data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg('mean')
    # The average value of col2 across the categories

    std = data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg(np.std)
    se = std / np.sqrt(n)
    # Standard deviation and standard error

    lower = st.t.interval(alpha = 0.95, df=n-1, loc = mean, scale = se)[0]
    upper = st.t.interval(alpha = 0.95, df =n-1, loc = mean, scale = se)[1]
    # Calculates the upper and lower bounds using SciPy

    for upper, mean, lower, y in zip(upper, mean, lower, cat):
        plt.plot((lower, mean, upper), (y, y, y), 'b.-')
        # for 'b.-': 'b' means 'blue', '.' means dot, '-' means solid line
    plt.yticks(
        range(len(n)),
        list(data.groupby(col1, as_index = False)[col2].count()[col1])
        )
```

Given hypothetical data:

```
cat = ['a'] * 10 + ['b'] * 10 + ['c'] * 10
a = np.linspace(0.1, 5.0, 10)
b = np.linspace(0.5, 7.0, 10)
c = np.linspace(7.5, 20.0, 10)
rating = np.concatenate([a, b, c])

dat_dict = dict()
dat_dict['cat'] = cat
dat_dict['rating'] = rating
test_dat = pd.DataFrame(dat_dict)
```

which would look like this (but with more rows of course):

| cat | rating |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0.10000 |
| a | 0.64444 |
| b | 0.50000 |
| b | 0.12222 |
| c | 7.50000 |
| c | 8.88889 |

We can use the function to plot a difference in means with a confidence interval:

```
plot_diff_in_means(data = test_dat, col1 = 'cat', col2 = 'rating')
```

which gives us the following graph:

[image]