# How to plot Time Series Line Plot from multiple dataframe columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

I have the following DataFrame `nq` for which I want to plot a Line Plot.
The columns -1,-2 etc. indicate user score before and after the Date given in `date` column, i.e., if `nq.date = 2020-10-23` then `nq.-1 =2020-10-22`. I tried the following code but it produces a `KeyError: (-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`. Is there a way to fix this?

**nq**

```
UserId     |   date                 |-7|-6|-5|-4|-3|-2|-1|0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7
     1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |5 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0  
     2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |2 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |8 |0 |0 |0    
     3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |3 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247 |0 |7 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0
```

**code**

```
nq.plot(kind='line',x=nq[-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], y=nq[-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].mean())
```

Comment: What should the graph look like?

Comment: @ipj the x axis should have labels from -7 to 7 and y axis should have the mean of the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
nq.iloc[:,2:].mean().plot(kind='line')
```

result:

[image]

To combine mean and std on chart try:

```
nq.iloc[:,2:].mean().plot(kind='line', label='mean')
nq.iloc[:,2:].std().plot(kind='line', label='std')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: How to add the standard deviation to the plot?

Comment: Is there a way to have the std as a shadow on the mean line?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747313/how-to-plot-confidence-interval-in-python